# How do I add an image to an RTF file using Python

Tags: python

I am quite new to Python but I have made some code which will write a string to an RTF file but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do the same with an image file.

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("FATS5\A.JPG")

with open('TextDrop/TESTINGN.rtf', 'a') as f:
    f.write(img)
```

Obviously the above code does not work because the Write command works only for strings. Is there another command I should be using for images?

I am hoping to avoid getting into working with Google Docs or Word which is why I am looking at RTF files (e.g. wordpad).

Comment: Do you have a specification for the RTF content?

Comment: The spec is here: https://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/Archive_References/[MSFT-RTF].pdf.  Deciphering the spec is proving more difficult than I anticipated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the RTF spec, you should be able to embed a JPEG directly into a RTF file.  I was unable to make that work.

Instead I convert the image to a Windows Bitmap (BMP) and write that to the file.  The first line written to the file is just boilerplate which I'm sure you'll recognize if you've worked with RTF files before.

```
import io
from PIL import Image
import sys

dpi = 96
twips_per_px = 72 * 20 // dpi
size_factor = 26.46  # found by experimentation, don't know how it's derived

def hexout(blist, file=sys.stdout):
    for block in range(0, len(blist), 39):
        print(blist[block:block+39].hex(), file=file)

def im_to_rtf(im_fn, rtf_fn):
    im = Image.open(im_fn, 'r')
    w, h = im.size
    bmp_io = io.BytesIO()
    im.save(bmp_io, 'bmp')
    im.close()
    bmp_io.seek(14)
    bmp_bytes = bmp_io.read()
    with open(rtf_fn, 'w') as f:
        print(r'{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}', file=f)
        print(r'{\pict\dibitmap0', file=f, end='')
        print(rf'\picw{w*size_factor:0.0f}', file=f, end='')
        print(rf'\pich{h*size_factor:0.0f}', file=f, end='')
        print(rf'\picwgoal{w*twips_per_px}\pichgoal{h*twips_per_px}', file=f)
        hexout(bmp_bytes, file=f)
        print(r'}\par}', file=f)
```